# Why does removing any of the wheres makes the query fast?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I will present a simplified version of my query:

```
SELECT item.prop1, item.prop2,
       COALESCE(item.prop3, parents.prop3, grandparents.prop3) AS p3
FROM items
  INNER JOIN parents ON item.parent_id = parents.id
  INNER JOIN grandparents ON parents.grandparent_id = grandparents.id
  INNER JOIN pivot ON pivot.item_id = items.id
  INNER JOIN users ON pivot.user_id = users.id
WHERE
  items.prop4 IS NULL
  AND COALESCE(parents.prop5, grandparents.prop5) = 8
  AND users.country_id IN (123)
```

This query is a bit slower than I can afford - it runs about 0.7 seconds.

While trying to optimize, I noticed that removing any of the last two lines make it run in 0.01-0.02 seconds.

I tried to split the filtering in two steps:

```
SELECT item.prop1, item.prop2, p3
FROM (
    SELECT item.prop1, item.prop2,
           COALESCE(item.prop3, parents.prop3, grandparents.prop3) AS p3,
           users.country_id as country
    FROM items
      INNER JOIN parents ON item.parent_id = parents.id
      INNER JOIN grandparents ON parents.grandparent_id = grandparents.id
      INNER JOIN pivot ON pivot.item_id = items.id
      INNER JOIN users ON pivot.user_id = users.id
    WHERE
      items.prop4 IS NULL
      AND COALESCE(parents.prop5, grandparents.prop5) = 8
) AS temp
WHERE temp.country IN (123)
```

This made no difference in the total running time. When I tried to execute only the subquery, it completed in about 0.01 seconds and return about 1200 rows. I would expect that filtering by these 1200 rows down to 570 by a single column shouldn't cost me half a second, should it?

I also tried another hierarchy like this:

```
SELECT item.prop1, item.prop2,
       COALESCE(item.prop3, parents.prop3, grandparents.prop3) AS p3
FROM items
  INNER JOIN parents ON item.parent_id = parents.id
  INNER JOIN grandparents ON parents.grandparent_id = grandparents.id
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT pivot.item_id as item
    FROM pivot
      INNER JOIN users ON pivot.user_id = users.id
    WHERE users.country_id IN (123)
  ) as country_items ON country_items.item = items.id
WHERE
  items.prop4 IS NULL
  AND COALESCE(parents.prop5, grandparents.prop5) = 8
```

Once again the subquery is fast (0.005 seconds, returns about 200000 rows) but whole thing together runs really slow.

What could cause such performance dip? I am almost leaning to involve my application to execute the last statement in two steps...

### Working solution

Selecting this constraint and employing `HAVING` solves the issue - this query completes in 0.015 seconds.

```
SELECT item.prop1, item.prop2,
       COALESCE(item.prop3, parents.prop3, grandparents.prop3) AS p3, users.country_id as country
FROM items
  INNER JOIN parents ON item.parent_id = parents.id
  INNER JOIN grandparents ON parents.grandparent_id = grandparents.id
  INNER JOIN pivot ON pivot.item_id = items.id
  INNER JOIN users ON pivot.user_id = users.id
WHERE
  items.prop4 IS NULL
  AND COALESCE(parents.prop5, grandparents.prop5) = 8
HAVING country IN (123)
```

I still do not understand the reasons here. I thought `COALESCE` was the slow one in `WHERE` and I tried selecting and `HAVING` it first but it didn't change the performance at all.

But how is this query different from my first attempt where I selected the same thing in a subquery? It seems like the same thing - a query selects 1200 rows and 570 of those are filtered out according to the country constraint.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  Normally a hierarchical structure is contained in a single table, not 3.

Comment: @RickJames I guess `parent`/`grandparent` name was misleading. It could be understood as `bag` & `warehouse`. It certainly is not an object of the same class. I find the actual tables and queries too big and complex to include all of the crime scene in the question...

Comment: Is `grandparents.prop5` supposed to be `prop5` or `prop6`?  The queries are inconsistent.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Eg give your DDL & query plans. Read intros to query/schema implementation/optimization in RDBMSs & your DBMS. PS HAVING is per group. Without GROUP BY it's like having its condition in a/the WHERE. Subqueries in isolation can be orders of magnitude faster than queryies involving joins, so they don't matter. Table statistics & query plans (join orders) do. Note COALESCE is in general not sargable.

Comment: Your 'working solution' [sic] has `having` *`country`* `in (123)`--not `country_id`--& is presumably always false, so no wonder things speed up. Please edit your question to be clear about what code exhibits what behaviour. But if you have an answer to that question then please post it as an answer, not an edit. Put clarifications in posts, not comments. You are not going to get a reasonable answer without DDL & query plans in your question. It is going to matter what order the joins are in, and if there is a faster query it will be because the estimated statistics/distributions will be wrong.

Comment: @philipxy thank you for your suggestions, I will try to make better examples for the future questions! I wrote up an answer on what I found. In this case I had to force MySQL to "start with the coalesces" and I didn't realize that wrapping statements in a subquery doesn't change the query plan as MySQL can interpret that I'm still asking for the same.

Comment: @philipxy as for the solution - it's `having country in (123)` because of `users.country_id as country` in the `select`.

Answer (score 1):

Using WHERE forces the query engine to perform additional lookups to the table's fields whereas a query without a WHERE would simply return the results.

In order to make this query run faster, you probably need to add indexes to your table.

First of all run the same query by adding `EXPLAIN` before your `SELECT`. This will give you a nice overview of how many rows were examined, what's the key cardinality etc.

If this is a standard query you're using, I suggest you [add an index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) for all 3 columns. If you plan to query the columns separately, you can add an index to each column you need to query, but don't overdo it as the table will become slower.

If you run `EXPLAIN` after you've added the indexes you'd get a significantly lower count of rows examined I guess.

If your table already has indexes, you can hint the MySQL server by using a [`USE INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) hint.

Comment: There already is an index for all of the `WHERE` columns. The `EXPLAIN` told me `Using index` only for the non-coalesced constraints and `Using where` for the others, which I expected. But the problem is that even `WHERE COALESCE...` works fast, but coupling it with another fast constraint that uses an index makes it all slow down 50 times...

Comment: My guess is that you can't avoid a temp table which slows things down here since you're comparing to `COALESCE`. What happens if you return the COALESCE as a field and  use `HAVING` to get the results you're interested in?

Comment: I am really surprised - `HAVING` helps in an unexpected way (see edit in question). First I selected the `COALESCE` and used `HAVING` on it - it didn't change the performance at all (makes sense since it still makes a temp table and filters it all in memory). However, before replying you in comment, I tried selecting the other problematic thing and it helped. I have no idea why this worked and I can't even understand why did I try it... probably desparate enough to try everything :) Do you have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Not 100% certain. You can add the `EXPLAIN` output, that might help :)

Comment: Ah, I see! It turns out that the subquery got unwrapped anyways - explain always started with the people table even if there was a subquery specified that should be executed and made into a temporary table first... However having finally allowed to ignore the `people` and started with the `grandparents` table that puts the huge `items` a bit further down the line and sooner narrows it :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a MySQL guru but the issue is solved and here is what I think (based on some `EXPLAIN`ing by mysql) was going on. The problem seems to that both of the problematic conditions

```
  AND COALESCE(parents.prop5, grandparents.prop5) = 8
  AND users.country_id IN (123)
```

are at the most distant ends of the joins. MySQL always decided to start working with the `users` table making it build a huge temporary table and only applying `COALESCE` on the final joined temporary table.

If `AND users.country_id IN (123)` is removed, MySQL can `COALESCE(parents.prop5, grandparents.prop5)` right away, test that condition, join the other tables and throw out the output. If `AND COALESCE(parents.prop5, grandparents.prop5) = 8` is removed, there is no need to make a temporary table for filtering - all the `WHERE` conditions can be applied separately before joining it all.

The following queries that I tried are different declarations for the same thing. I didn't know that MySQL will notice that and execute them in the very same order.

```
SELECT item.prop1, item.prop2,
       COALESCE(item.prop3, parents.prop3, grandparents.prop3) AS p3
FROM items
  INNER JOIN parents ON item.parent_id = parents.id
  INNER JOIN grandparents ON parents.grandparent_id = grandparents.id
  INNER JOIN pivot ON pivot.item_id = items.id
  INNER JOIN users ON pivot.user_id = users.id
WHERE
  items.prop4 IS NULL
  AND COALESCE(parents.prop5, grandparents.prop5) = 8
  AND users.country_id IN (123)

SELECT item.prop1, item.prop2, p3
FROM (
    SELECT item.prop1, item.prop2,
           COALESCE(item.prop3, parents.prop3, grandparents.prop3) AS p3,
           users.country_id as country
    FROM items
      INNER JOIN parents ON item.parent_id = parents.id
      INNER JOIN grandparents ON parents.grandparent_id = grandparents.id
      INNER JOIN pivot ON pivot.item_id = items.id
      INNER JOIN users ON pivot.user_id = users.id
    WHERE
      items.prop4 IS NULL
      AND COALESCE(parents.prop5, grandparents.prop5) = 8
) AS temp
WHERE temp.country IN (123)
```

The third query once again starts with filtering `users` and then joins everything together to apply `COALESCE` when everything is read.

```
SELECT item.prop1, item.prop2,
       COALESCE(item.prop3, parents.prop3, grandparents.prop3) AS p3
FROM items
  INNER JOIN parents ON item.parent_id = parents.id
  INNER JOIN grandparents ON parents.grandparent_id = grandparents.id
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT pivot.item_id as item
    FROM pivot
      INNER JOIN users ON pivot.user_id = users.id
    WHERE users.country_id IN (123)
  ) as country_items ON country_items.item = items.id
WHERE
  items.prop4 IS NULL
  AND COALESCE(parents.prop5, grandparents.prop5) = 8
```

### The solution

This query finally makes it start from the fat end: join a couple of tables in memory, apply coalesce, then take only the necessary rows (passing constraints) in the following joins.

```
SELECT item.prop1, item.prop2,
       COALESCE(item.prop3, parents.prop3, grandparents.prop3) AS p3, users.country_id as country
FROM items
  INNER JOIN parents FORCE INDEX (parents_grandparent_id) ON item.parent_id = parents.id
  INNER JOIN grandparents ON parents.grandparent_id = grandparents.id
  INNER JOIN pivot ON pivot.item_id = items.id
  INNER JOIN users ON pivot.user_id = users.id
WHERE
  items.prop4 IS NULL
  AND COALESCE(parents.prop5, grandparents.prop5) = 8
```

Comment: HAVING filters groups not rows--missing GROUP BY means GROUP BY (), disallowing HAVING columns outside aggregates unless they have the same value in every row--you are almost certainly getting wrong answers or luckily getting right answers--use SET SQLMODE="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" before 5.7 to be stopped from this error. HAVING has no optmization for 8.0 & below so it is not helping anyway. Your lack of a [mcve] is preventing us from helping you, while you are just guessing re why the change & your code is wrong.

Comment: @philipxy sorry, but I don't see how could I make an example that would reproduce the behaviour. Btw after having found the issue I managed to change `HAVING` to a `FORCE INDEX` solution now.

Comment: As I said, give DDL, statistics & query plans. Give as much of a [mcve] as you can. We could have got you to where you are (and will be) right away.